# Can't get "View in Browser" or tool tip to work in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't get two features in Microsoft's Visual Studio Code to work.
1) I can't activate the "View in Browser" extension.
2)  The tool tip feature isn't displayed in the editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you re-install the latest version from [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Open vscode, press F1, then type **'ext install**[space]', [space] = space key; 
Select "*Extensions: Install Extension*", then type '**view in browser**'; Click bottom right 'tree' like logo to install extension; then Restart Now.

Open vscode, create an html file, then press Ctrl + F1 to view the html in your default browser.

Reference:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.view-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **View in browser** extension, I suggest you to use **View in Default** Application Extension.

Press F1 and narrow down the list commands by typing **extension**

Select the Extensions: Install Extension command.

Search for this extension by typing in the text **view in default application**

Once installed, you will be prompted to restart your instance of Visual Studio Code to use the extension

After saving your HTML file, press first **ctrl+k** and then **ctrl+b**.Your HTML file will be open in your default browser

Answer (score 0):

Go To File - > Settings.
It will open a new window to the right.
Add your proxy settings there as:
"http.proxy" : "value".
Restart the Visual Studio Code.
It should work.